# Does a single FermCap addition control both boilovers and blowoffs?

Tags: boilover, blow-off, foam

I love FermCap for controlling boilovers. I add a few drops (less than recommended) as the wort comes up to boiling. It allows me to do other things during the boil to shorten my brew day.

Here's what I'm wondering:

The directions say to add a drop per gallon at the "start of fermentation". Does my boil addition count for that? Can I just add the recommended amount for my final volume to the boil and trust that all of it will make it into the fermenter?

Comment: Excellent question on a little-discussed product. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, a kettle addition of Fermcap does not eliminate the need for it in the fermenter.  If you need it there, you have to add more.

Comment: I always thought the boiling process broke some of it down which compounds the loss of its effectiveness as some of it had already been used up preventing the boil-over foam. Am I wrong on the heat part?

Comment: AFAIK, you are correct.